# Can't start Uvicorn server from a Python Click Command

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-click, uvicorn

I am trying to create a [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) command that starts a [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) server but can't get the server to start.
I get a feeling it may be related to asyncio, which I am not very familiar with it.
Any help is appreciated

#### Works as Expected

```
>>> import uvicorn
>>> uvicorn.run("downloader.mock_server:app")
INFO:     Started server process [84462]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

#### Click Command

```
@cli.command()
@click.option("--host", default="http://0.0.0.0", help="host")
@click.option("--port", default=8000, help="port")
@click.option("--reload", is_flag=True, help="Should Reload")
def mock_server(host, port, reload):
    """Starts Mock server"""
    uvicorn.run("downloader.mock_server:app", host=host, port=port, reload=False)
    print("Help!") #never reaches this line + server does not start
```

Running Command:

```
>>> ~
.venv ❯ downloader mock-server
Starting Server

.venv ❯
```

With click, program exits at `run()` step, event if I try putting a breakpoint after nothing happens.

I also tried using the decorator provided [here](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/85#issuecomment-43378930) but it did not help:

```
.venv ❯ downloader mock-server
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'mock_server' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```